# Inventory Management with GP 2010 and QR barcode

Tags: qr-code

My company currently uses GP 2010 for inventory. I am trying to figure out a way to use mobile devices to scan a qr code from an item in inventory and have it remove or add the item in or out of GP 2010. I have a little experience in .NET from college courses and I'm unfamiliar with GP 2010. I have no idea where to begin. I hope I have given all the information necessary. Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you.